# Hanging references using \fullcite

Tags: biblatex, citing, indentation, apa-style

I need `APA` style hanging references using `\fullcite`. For example

[image]

I need `\fullcite` because I want the reference cited where I want in the document, unlike at the end of the document using `\cite`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**

The latest version of `biblatex-apa` (2.6 or above) now fixes this problem, so you should update rather than use the solution below. `biblatex-apa` now provides two commands: `\fullcite` which makes an inline reference (with no hanging indent) and `\fullcitebib` which makes a fake bibliography entry, with a hanging indent.

If you are making a categorised bibliography for a CV, for example, there are better ways to achieve this than using multiple `\fullcitebib` commands.  See e.g.

- [biblatex: List of publications in the CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115143/2693)

**Original answer**

The problem is that the standard `\fullcite` command in biblatex assumes that the full citation should be included in the text.  So what's needed is to redefine the `\fullcite` command so that it actually makes a small bibliography when called.  Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
      {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}
           {\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}
       \begin{thebibliography}\thebibitem}
      {\usedriver
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}
      {\thebibitem}
      {\end{thebibliography}}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{reese} % This citation will appear in the text

%\printbibliography % if you also have a bibliography

\end{document}
```

This should now do what you want.

For multiple citations, the citations aren't sorted automatically, but appear in the order in the `fullcite` command. This is because the `apa` style sets `sortcites=false`; to get the `\fullcites` to be sorted you can add `sortcites=true` to your `biblatex` options, but I suspect this will make other citations not fully APA compatible.

I should mention that the `\fullcite` command is not really appropriate for making larger lists of references; `biblatex` has other ways to make partial bibliographies.

Comment: This one works, but I need APA style references. \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex} does not work.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've updated my answer. Does this example work for you?

Comment: This is what I had initially. But this does not give "hanging references".

Comment: Now I see.  (If you had included this example in your question we might have progressed a little faster. :-) ).  The problem is that the biblatex-apa doesn't define a `\fullcite` command, and so uses the biblatex default, which assumes that the reference should blend in with the rest of the text.  What exactly are you trying to do with these `\fullcite`s anyway?  Maybe there's an alternative.

Comment: Sorry about not putting it before, in the question? I need `\fullcite` to be able to put the whole citation in the document with other text. I want to be able to put text around these citations. Unlike doing, for example, [1] and the citation if at the end of the document. And these citations need to be hanging and in APA style

Comment: Ok.  Now I've updated the answer again.  I think this does what you want.

Comment: Hi Alan, there is one issue though. There is no period after each of the fields. For example, `Fan, D. and Song, L.(2009)Text categorization method based on fuzzy correlation analysis
Environmental and computer science. icecs '09. (pp. 196-198)doi:10.1109/ICECS.2009.24.`

Comment: @yO2gO I just posted some updated code.  There were a couple of other problems too, including missing spaces.  The new code works (finally.)  `biblatex` is a complicated beast.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "better ways to achieve this"? Which ways?

Comment: @MaxN I've added a link to a better way.

Comment: @AlanMunn there are many examples given how to filter my bibliography, but not how to actually style them (without affecting the actual bibliography in the end of the document. Hence I asked a new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414716/options-for-styling-fullcite