# \fullcite not printing references in APA format.

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am using `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` for formatting references in APA format. 
I am using `\fullcite` to print the full reference in APA format as I have to describe the printed reference. In my case I cannot use the `\printbibliography` function to print the reference. The problem using `\fullcite` is that it is not printing reference in APA format, it is using `AND` instead of `&`. 
Here is the example:

using `\fullcite`

```
Darwin, C., Ekman, P., and Prodger, P. (2002). The expression of the emo-
tions in man and animals. Oxford University Press, USA
```

using `\printbibliography`

```
Darwin, C., Ekman, P., & Prodger, P. (2002). The expression of the emotions
in man and animals. Oxford University Press, USA
```

My question is how to incorporate `&` instead of `AND` in the `\fullcite` function. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to tex.sx! Although your question is not identical to this one: [hanging references using \fullcite](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13272/hanging-references-using-fullcite), the solution posted there solves your problem as well.

Comment: @Alan Is it possible to add a counter to the `\fullcite` function so that I can print the number of the reference, I know about counters but I have no idea about how to integrate it in a function such as `\fullcite` any pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Because the `\fullcite` method isn't really intended for this.  Are you trying to make a bibliography with different categories?  If that's the case, you can do that in `biblatex`, but without using `\fullcite`.

Comment: I am creating a annotated bibliography using `biblatex-apa`. In this process I also need to add numbers such as: `1. Ref` `2. Ref` to the bibliography, that is why I asked the question regarding counter integrated with `\fullcite`

Comment: @Neo_Me I removed your "Solved" edit.  Having accepted an answer suffices to show that it has been solved, and leaving the question as it is may be more helpful to others with the same problem in the future.

Comment: @Alan No problem! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of `biblatex-apa` (2.6 or above) now fixes this problem, so you should update. `biblatex-apa` now provides two commands: `\fullcite` which makes an inline reference (with no hanging indent) and `\fullcitebib` which makes a fake bibliography entry, with a hanging indent.

If you are making a categorised bibliography for a CV, for example, there are better ways to achieve this than using multiple `\fullcitebib` commands.

To make an annotated bibliography using `\fullcitebib` commands you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\newcounter{bibnum}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
  {\renewenvironment*{thebibliography}
  {\list
     {\stepcounter{bibnum}\thebibnum.\ }
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.65\bibhang}
      %
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
  \begin{thebibliography}\thebibitem}
  {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}
  {\thebibitem}
  {\end{thebibliography}}

\begin{document}

\fullcitebib{glashow}

Some annotations.

\fullcitebib{herrmann}

Some annotations
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]