# APA conform \bibentry in document's body using natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I would like to cite some bibentries in full text in the body of my document. @Gonzalo Medina provided a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49048/how-to-cite-one-bibentry-in-full-length-in-the-body-text) to an almost identical problem which is (marginally modified) shown below.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author00,
title = {{A Title}},
journal = {Alpha},
year = {2008},
author= {Author, A},
address = {London}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

A regular citation of \cite{author00}.
A full in-text cite of \bibentry{author00}.

\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

This works fine for `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, but when using apa.bst it throws an error. However, I am committed to both, natbib and apa.

Further would it be nice if it could be shown that possible multi-line references are indented from the second line on.

Comment: I don't know how different the `apalike.bst` bibliography style is compared to the `apa` style, but it is compatible with `bibentry`.  If you're willing to use `biblatex`, then the `biblatex-apa` package provides exactly the functionality you require, and is also APA compliant.  See [\fullcite not printing references in APA style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13348/2693) for an example.

Answer (score 5):

Using the apalike.bst as suggested by @Alan Munn and the `hanging` package I have been able to do what I want.

The code below shows bibentries in the document's body as in the
'References' with the possibility to add some comment in between.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author00,
    author= {Author, A and Buthor, B},
    title = {{Article's Title: Long Enough to Ensure Multiple Rows}},
    journal = {Journal Name},
    year = {2000},
    volume = {10},
    pages = {217-234},
    number = {4}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\nobibliography*
\newcommand\hangbibentry[1]{%
    \smallskip\par\hangpara{1em}{1}\bibentry{#1}\smallskip\par %{indent}{afterline}
}

\begin{document}

A regular citation of \cite{author00}. Followed by \lipsum[1]
\hangbibentry{author00}
And a full in-text cite followed by \lipsum[2]

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]