# Avoiding \bibentry to be shown in regular \bibliography, using natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib, bibentry

In an earlier question - [bibentry in documents body](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54424/apa-conform-bibentry-in-documents-body-using-natbib/54523#54523) - I was looking for a possibility to have `\bibitems` appear in in my documents body. This was solved using the `bibentry` package.

As a follow-up I would now like to have the `\bibitem` appear in the body *only*, and not in the regular reference list in the end at all.

Is it possible to define something like a `\bibentry*` that prevents the entry from being shown? Or any other way to get what I want? I cannot get around using natbib...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question. The `bibentry` package provides the command `\bibentry{<key>}` to generate full citations in the running text. The "source" of the keys (i.e., the name(s) of the bib file(s) that contain the raw entries) is shoud be indicated via the instruction `\nobibliography{<bibfile(s)>}`. Note that the `\nobibliography` command serves only to indicate the names of the bib files -- it doesn't do the "double duty" of also generating a bibliography at the place in the tex file where it's encountered.

If you do want to generate a "regular" list of references (likely towards the end of the document) *as well as* in-text references, you should use a `\bibliography` command, as usual, where the references should be listed. In this case, you should use the `\nobibliography*{<bibfiles>}` command instead of `\nobibliography{<bibfiles>}`, as is explained in the user guide of the `bibentry` package. Use of the "starred" command will help suppress spurious warning and error messages from BibTeX and LaTeX.

Comment: In fact you have to use just `\nobibliography*`, not `\nobibliography*{<bibfiles>}`.

Anyway, I think this does not solve the problem issued here. The question is how to have some entries in the body of the text, which do not appear also in the bibliography at the end. `\nobibliography` does not solve it, because he has other entries that must appear at the end. `\nobibliography*` do not solve it, because all the cited entries will appear.

I have no answer neither... but I am looking for it.

Comment: @AlejandroDC Did you find the solution for this? I know it it was a long time ago... but I'm looking for it now!

Comment: Hi @CarlosViegas. No, I did not. I finally added these items by hand (taken from the bbl). Sorry about that. But you can follow this discution in the duplicated question, I think there are pretty nice alternatives.