# Suppress printing of only \bibentry references with natbib?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, subdividing, bibentry

This question was [basically asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64425/avoiding-bibentry-to-be-shown-in-regular-bibliography-using-natbib), but I think that the only answer didn't quite understand the question so I thought I'd try again. I'm writing a paper in which I need to have references show up in two places:  a special list of "key references" in its own section, and a bibliography containing the rest of the references that were cited in the text. I thought that bibentry would do it, so the document looks something like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

\section{Amazing idea}

Chicken chicken chicken \citep{chicken:2010fj}.  Chicken chicken, chicken \citep{turkey:2010jk}.

\section{Key References}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \bibentry{lemur:2009ii}
\item \bibentry{gibbon:2011jk}
\end{enumerate}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{amazing.bib}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite do it, as the resulting document presents the lemur and gibbon bibentry references correctly in the "Key References" section, but *also* prints them in the bibliography at the end of the document.  Ideally, the only entries in the bibliography would be the chicken and turkey \citep references.  I'd like it to look like:

> **Key references**
>
> 1. Lemur, L. (2009). *Lemur*, 12(4):1-7.
> 2. Gibbon, G. (2011). *Gibbon*, 135:1002-1009.
>
> **References**
>
> Chicken, C. (2010). *Chicken*. Chicken Press, Coop.
>
> Turkey, T. (2010). *Turkey*, 7(4):E231.

What it actually looks like:

> **Key references**
>
> 1. Lemur, L. (2009). *Lemur*, 12(4):1-7.
> 2. Gibbon, G. (2011). *Gibbon*, 135:1002-1009.
>
> **References**
>
> Chicken, C. (2010). *Chicken*. Chicken Press, Coop.
>
> Gibbon, G. (2011). *Gibbon*, 135:1002-1009.
>
> Lemur, L. (2009). *Lemur*, 12(4):1-7.
>
> Turkey, T. (2010). *Turkey*, 7(4):E231.

Is there any way to achieve this with the current method, or is there some other (possibly easier!?) way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated  in the answer to the other question `bibentry` is not suitable for the task at hand  (without modifications). If you want to give `biblatex` a try, it is easy to set it up for what you want to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[natbib,style=authoryear]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@article{nature, 
   author      =   {Rosa Rademakers and Manuela Neumann and Ian R. Mackenzie}, 
   title      =   {Advances in understanding the molecular basis of frontotemporal dementia - elongated title}, 
   journal      =   {Nature Reviews Neurology}, 
   volume      =   {8}, 
   year      =   {2012}, 
   pages      =   {423-434}, 
   doi         =   {10.1038/nrneurol.2012.117}} 
@article{fuente, 
   author      =   {D. de la Fuente and J.G. Castaño and M. Morcillo}, 
   title      =   {Long-term atmospheric corrosion of zinc}, 
   journal      =   {Corrosion Science}, 
   volume      =   {49}, 
   year      =   {2007}, 
   pages      =   {1420-1436},
   url = {www.elsevier.com/locate/corsci},
   } 
 @incollection{Rocca2007a,
   author = {Rocca, Emmanuel and Mirambet, Fran\c{c}ois},
   booktitle = {Corrosion of Metallic Heritage Artefacts: Investigation, Conservation and Prediction of Long Term Behaviour},
   chapter = {18},
   editor = {Philippe Dillmann and Pedro Piccardo and Gerard Beranger},
   pages = {308-334},
   title = {{Corrosion inhibitors for metallic artefacts: temporary protection}},
   year = {2007}}
\end{filecontents} 

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{keyreferences}

\defbibenvironment{keyrefs}
  {\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item}

\begin{document} 
Test \citet{nature}\addtocategory{keyreferences}{nature}

another test \cite{fuente} and \citep{Rocca2007a}

\printbibliography[env=keyrefs,category=keyreferences,title={Key References}]
\printbibliography[notcategory=keyreferences]
\end{document}
```

The key issue is to create a `category` for the key references. After that we can use the `category` and `notcategory` options to `\printbibliography` command to filter the  references.  Also the `natbib` option allows us to use standard `natbib` commands for citations.

Since you want the key references to be printed as an `enumerate` list, we can use the command `\defbibenviornment` to use `enumerate` as the wrapper  environment for them, and use  the `env=...` option to specify it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Guido!  I *had* been meaning to try biblatex, and that was a great introduction.  I managed to simplify it a bit by using  \fullcite to enumerate the key references (they don't appear in the main text), but I learned a lot from your answer!

Comment: If the key references are not cited in the main text there is an easy solution using `natbib` and `bibentry`

Comment: How?  I tried with bibentry and natbib;  what I got was the "actually looks like" version above.  The document in my question is just a minimal version of the actual document, exactly as it would appear.

Comment: You suggested not using bibentry, but is there a way to add an item in the same way? I mean, to use something like `\bibentry{Citation:2001}` without having to really use `\cite{Citation:2001}`?

Comment: I'm a computer scientist and I cannot get this to work :-)  Too bad they make the best typesetting software so very difficult.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, however it may be useful to have a BibTeX-only solution. Using `multibib` and `bibentry` together this is relatively simple: define and show an additional bibliography (here: `q`) for the normal references (use `\citeq`, `citepq`, etc.) and show the key references as `bibentry` while suppressing the list for these references with `\nobibliography`. `multibib` is compatible with `natbib`. Compile sequence:

```
pdflatex mbib.tex
bibtex q
bibtex mbib
pdflatex mbib
pdflatex mbib
```

MWE:

*mbib.tex*

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{q}{References}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

\section{Amazing idea}

Chicken chicken chicken \citepq{chicken:2010fj}.  Chicken chicken, chicken \citepq{turkey:2010jk}.

\section*{Key references}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \bibentry{lemur:2009ii}.
\item \bibentry{gibbon:2011jk}.
\end{enumerate}

\bibliographystyleq{apalike}
\bibliographyq{mbibref.bib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\nobibliography{mbibref.bib}
\end{document}
```

*mbibref.bib*

```
@book{chicken:2010fj,
    author = {Chicken, C},
    title = {Chicken},
    publisher = {Chicken Press},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{turkey:2010jk,
    author = {Turkey, T},
    title = {Turkey},
    publisher = {Turkey Press},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{lemur:2009ii,
    author = {Lemur, L},
    title = {Lemur},
    publisher = {Lemur Press},
    year = {2009}
}
@book{gibbon:2011jk,
    author = {Gibbon, G},
    title = {Gibbon},
    publisher = {Gibbon Press},
    year = {2011}
}
```

---

If you don't want to change `\citep` to `\citepq` in an existing document then you can copy the definition of `\citepq` into `\citep` and keep using the original command name in the document.

However, because `\citepq` uses `\citep` internally you should first store the original definition in a helper command like `\origcitep` and use that in the new definition.

Relevant code snippet:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{q}{References}
\makeatletter
\let\origcitep\citep
\def\citep{\let \@citex \mb@@citex \let \@newciteauxhandle \@auxoutq \csname origcitep\endcsname}
\makeatother
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}
\section{Amazing idea}

Chicken chicken chicken \citep{chicken:2010fj}.  Chicken chicken, chicken \citep{turkey:2010jk}.
```

Similarly you can redefine `\citet` and `\cite` as well.

Comment: Clever. But in the context of an existing document, it would be nice if I would not have to change all existing citations. Is it also possible to define a `\bibentryq` instead?

Comment: @ChristophThiede see edit for a method to use the original cite commands.

Comment: Fair, but you would still have to do this for `\citeauthor`, `\citeyear`, etc., too, which is why I do not find this solution maximally elegant. Anyway, thanks!