# Alternative to bibentry (not biblatex)

Tags: bibtex, natbib, texniccenter, bibentry

Basically I have the same issue as in here:

[Suppress printing of only \bibentry references with natbib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93845/suppress-printing-of-only-bibentry-references-with-natbib)

I want to be able to use the characteristics of `bibentry` (i.e., I want to print the full citation *inside* my document and *at the same time* I want to have a `bibliography` with all the elements of my .bib file (it's easier to just see the question I pointed above).

The thing is that the answer provided is using `biblatex`.  I don't need much convincing to switch to it, but for several reasons (mainly "political") I **have** to use `natbib`.

Any suggestions?

## Edit

I've recently tried the answer provided by Karl, but it doesn't seem to work while building the whole project in TeXnicCenter (MikTeX 2.9). Here is my code (it's the same as Karl's, but the References file is sepparate and has exactly the same content as Karl's example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

This is a citation \citep{art1}

\section{Test}

This is a bibentry

\begin{enumerate}
\item \bibentry{book1}
\end{enumerate}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine for me (WinEdt 8.1 and MiKTeX 2.9)... Maybe is it a TeXnicCenter fault?

Comment: @karlkoeller yeap, I'm beginning to think it has something to do with the way it handles "projects".  I would like to know if someone has the same issue or if it's just me

Comment: Did you discover what your problem was?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure to understand correctly your needs, but try the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{examplebib.bib}
@article{art1,
author="First Last",
title="A fictitious journal article",
year=1900,
journal="Journal of nothingness",
volume=2,
pages="1-2"
}

@book{boo1,
author="Respectable Writer",
title="A silly book",
year=2000,
publisher="PublishCo",
address="Somewhere"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

This is a citation \citep{art1}

\section{Test}

This is a bibentry

\begin{enumerate}
\item \bibentry{art1}
\end{enumerate}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{examplebib}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If you read the linked question, I think Mario wants any entry used as a `\bibentry` to *not* appear in the list of references.

Comment: @AlanMunn no no, this is exactly what I wanted, but it doesn't seem to work when I implement it the way I'm using it (I want it to be inside a .sty)

Comment: I was wondering if there isn't any other workaround, like trying to implement the `\bibentry` command...

Comment: @MarioS.E. Take a look at `bibentry.sty` and see if you can somehow extract its definition.

Comment: @MarioS.E. So then I truly don't understand your question.  You'll need to explain how Karl's solution doesn't work for you. (And the linked question is a bit of a red herring anyway, since the requirements there are different.)

Comment: @AlanMunn It's quite complicated (and I'm afraid it's one of the limitations ot TeX.SE) that when a LaTeX rookie like me tries to play developer encounters problems that do not occur in a MWE.  What I'm really trying to do is to improve my thesis template package ([`feupphdteses`](http://ctan.org/pkg/feupphdteses)) in order to be able to print a "publications" page at the beginning containing the author's own publications while doing his/her thesis.

Comment: @AlanMunn I actually thought that using `bibentry` would solve my issue, but somehow something is going wrong, and I'm not sure where.  That's why I asked the question, to be completely sure I was implementing it the right way (at least in a MWE context).  Unfortunately, even by following all the steps presented by Karl (i.e., loading `bibetry` after `natbib` and writing `\nobibliography*` right after it I still get errors

Comment: This solution doesn't work when using TeXnicCenter and building a project.  It only works as an unique file.