# \bibentry equivalent with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibentry

I have the following problem: in preparing a proposal, I need some references to be stated in the text, and so far I was able to do this using the `\bibentry` command. However, the problem was that when printing the bibliography those items also showed up there, and this didn't make any sense as I just needed the entries to show up only once in the document. Now I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93845/suppress-printing-of-only-bibentry-references-with-natbib) that explains how to solve the problem using biblatex. But now the problem is that I don't know how to emulate the `bibentry` command to place references wherever I want.

Comment: Isn't that more or less a `\fullcite` (plus minus some minor modifications (that heavily depend on the style you use)? If you can give more details (on the style you use as well as the use case) we might be able to help with more specific pointers.

Comment: See also the (almost) duplicate [How to combine biber and bibentry?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135930/35864) as well as [How to make a bib entry appear also in the main document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44394/35864).

Comment: @moewe those links are quite useful, I think I can make it work with that info.

Comment: If you got your stuff working, a short heads-up so we can close this question as a duplicate would be nice. If something is not to your liking, please come back with a bit more info (see my first comment).