# Creating an annotated bibliography in APA

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, annotations

**Update:** When I tried implemented gusbrs's solution (below), I was having issues with the code as well, so I couldn't add my own references. Then I discovered that the issue had something to do with my 'references.bib' file (I'm adding this information in case someone else is having the same issue). I deleted the file and created a new one, and both my code and gusbrs's code started working. Finally, I was able to see my own references listed. One of two **follow-up questions** I have is, **(1)** how can I delete the numbers? I know my code is more complicated, but this is an assignment I need to submit. My professor asked for this specific format, so I need to stick to the code I included in the original question. Can anyone tell me how to delete the numbers, which is the only thing that does not adhere to the format I was asked to follow? I tried deleting the
`{\stepcounter{bibnum}\thebibnum.\ }`
but it messed with the APA formatting. **Also**, with my code, I only get 'Sentence case' capitalizing (i.e. capital on the first letter of the title). **(2)** How can I change it so that it respects the format in my 'references.bib' document? Some of the titles include languages or concepts that must be capitalized, and my code completely violates this.

**Original:** First of all, I'm a beginner in LaTeX, so I apologize if this is a stupid question. I'm trying to create an annotated bibliography using APA style. I found a sample code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13348/fullcite-not-printing-references-in-apa-format/13655#13655), which I was able to implement. (Note that I had to change `\thebibitem` for `\item` in order for the code to run properly.) Below is the code as I'm using it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\newcounter{bibnum}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
  {\renewenvironment*{thebibliography}
  {\list
     {\stepcounter{bibnum}\thebibnum.\ }
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.65\bibhang}
      %
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2         
\finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
  \begin{thebibliography}\item}
  {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}
  {\item}
  {\end{thebibliography}}

\begin{document}

\fullcitebib{glashow}

Some annotations.

\fullcitebib{herrmann}

Some annotations
\end{document}
```

And I get this result, as seen in the original post:
[image]

I know how to change the annotations myself (that one's pretty easy). But I don't know how to change the references. Where do I go to add my own articles and books to annotate and remove those two? Also, what part of the code do I have to change to get rid of the numbers? I would like to keep everything in the format as is, except for the numbering.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Even though `biblatex-apa` provides `\fullcitebib`, I believe you'd be better of, for what you are attempting to do, with `biblatex`'s regular `\fullcite` command used in combination with a simple `enumerate` environment. Those should suffice without further configuration for the purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed if you have recent (La)TeX installation
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
% \DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}% no longer needed if you have recent (La)TeX installation
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% \bibliography{...} is legacy format

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \fullcite{glashow}

  Some annotations.

\item \fullcite{herrmann}

  Some annotations
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you might want to consider a typical tool for the task, which allows you to keep annotations tied to your entries within your bib database. As this is an annotated bibliography, I assume it is made for your own consumption and thus an APA style is not really a strict requirement. Given that, `biblatex` offers the `reading` style, which prints, alongside the entries the `annotation`, `abstract`, `library` and `file` fields (you can control which are printed through load time options).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=reading]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\cite{gillies}

\cite{kastenholz}

\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm still having some issues. I've added an edit to my original question with two follow-up questions. I'd appreciate it if you (or someone else) would take a stab at it.

Comment: @Ernesto This is a Question & Answers site, and people contribute not just for the sake of assisting those who ask, but because each QA remains for any other person with a similar problem. But the usefulness of this depends on a proper relation between the question and the answer. So, you should not review your question to add new requirements which were not initially made and which any answer here would not have considered. You can, of course ask new questions and, if it helps, you can mention those are follow up questions and link to this one.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information, given that I'm new to this community. I will refrain from posting follow up questions such as my question (2) in my update. However, I think I did not articulate my original questions clearly in the first place. My first question was about not seeing my own references when compiling (which turns out had nothing to do with the code and I explained this) as well as trying to get rid of the numbers in the references. So in my update, I simply restated this, I did not mean to pass it as changing the requirements of my original question.

Comment: @Ernesto Then please be clear as to what is the "specific format" you are looking for in your question. (I don't promise to tackle it, but someone else might). You never mentioned which one it was, you just shared a piece of code you were trying to adapt. The numbers were actually _added_ by that piece of code, and are present in your original question, as they don't belong in the standard definition of `\fullcitebib`.

Comment: Besides, in your update, you mention you tried to implement this solution I proposed, but then mention you did not achieve to remove numbering through deleting `{\stepcounter{bibnum}\thebibnum.\ }` which does not make real sense, as this does not occur in my answer.

Comment: Again, thanks for sharing information regarding norms of communication on this platform--I'm taking mental notes. And I apologize for my lack of clarity and poor articulation. However, I did mention in the title that I was looking for APA style, and the code you provided gave me something that did not adhere to that format. The way you characterized my "update" in your last comment is not at all the idea I was trying to convey, so I'll attribute this to my poor articulation. Again, I apologize for any inconveniences, and I hope we can put the discussion about all my shortcomings to rest.