# Displaying selected bibliographic items in the body of the text

Tags: biblatex, citing, mla-style

I have to prepare a `beamer` presentation on the topic of  citations and bibliographies. So I should be able to display selected bibliographic items in the slides as examples in most of the slides. I will be having a main `.bib` file. So how can I display selected bibliographic items in arbitrary places in the main body of the text?

I am using `biblatex` with the `biblatex-mla` style.

Comment: I've edited your question to reflect the fact that you're using `biblatex-mla`. This was really important information that you should have mentioned in your question originally. (As a result, two people gave good answers that don't actually work for you.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `biblatex-mla` package doesn't define a `\fullcite` command (it would have been very helpful to have mentioned that you were using this package in your question). Adapting some code (and naming convention) from the `biblatex-apa` package, based on [Hanging references using \fullcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13272/2693), here is a solution to your problem. Since MLA uses different author name ordering in footnote references and bibliography references but you want to be able to display both, we define a `\fullcitebib` command which will insert a properly formatted full bibliography entry in the text and a `\fullcitefoot` command which will insert a properly formatted footnote-style entry.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=mla,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\footcite}{\footcites}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1.5em}
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitefoot}
  {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}
   {\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
   \list{}
   {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
     \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}\item}
  {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}
  {\item}
  {\endlist\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
  {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}
   {\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
   \list{}
   {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
     \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}\item}
  {\usedriver
    {}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}
  {\item}
  {\endlist\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}
\makeatother
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize} uncomment this if you want footnotes smaller
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
This is a full citation in  footnote style: \fullcitefoot{Bli74}.

This is a full citation in bibliography style: \fullcitebib{Bli74}
\end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
 \printbibliography
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: It works well. One small change needs to be done. MLA does not invert author's name in footnote citation. So all the entries show author names as they are (without inversion). Let the `\fullbibcite` command remain as it is, because I can use it to show how footnote citations appear. So there should be another command to show entires with inverted author names.

Comment: @nixnotwin I've updated the answer to give you both options.

Comment: That worked as well. If you don't mind I need one more feature. The `\printbibliography` prints all the entries on one slide. So only 4 items are visible and rest (about 10) are invisible. Can there be an option to display a limited number of items, and rest pushed to the next slides.

Comment: @nixnotwin Add `[allowframebreaks]` to the frame command that contains the bibliography.

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Comment: @AlanMunn mla.cbx actually does define a \fullcite command. It works with biblatex 1.0.

Comment: @Audrey I don't have `biblatex 1.0` any more. :)  Anyway, I don't think it would deal with both the footnote version and the bib version.  It seems that `biblatex-mla` really needs some work.

Comment: @AlanMunn `\footcite` gives a full citation this first time an entry is cited. biblatex-mla's code is messy (the author even says so in file headers), but it *works* with 1.0. Until it gets updated, reverting back to this version is probably the best solution to all these style issues we've been having to look at lately.

Comment: This is super helpful.  Thank you so much for putting this out into the world

Answer (score 16):

You may use [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and its `\fullcite` macro. Note that is not necessary to typeset the full bibliography.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\fullcite{Bli74}
\end{frame}

% \begin{frame}
% \printbibliography
% \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `biblatex-mla` doesn't provide a `\fullcite` command (not surprising, since it's heavily footnote driven).  So this solution as it stands won't work with `style=mla`.

Comment: @AlanMunn You are right. The tex document fails to compile. Is there any other way I can address the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `bibentry` package. First, place `\usepackage{bibentry}` in the preamble. Then use the `\bibentry{AuthorYear}` to display the full bibliography entry anywhere in the document.

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\begin{document}
    You should read this book: \bibentry{AuthorYear}.
    \bibliography{mybooks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does not work. I'm using bilatex-mla package.

Comment: It works if you add the `\nobibliography*` line in the preamble as it is shown in the example of the package author at https://www.stefaanlippens.net/bibentry/