# Hyperref Backref Outside of Bibliography: "What Links Here"

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, cross-referencing, indexing, back-referencing

I'd like to add a section in my document that provides context on multiple figures of the main text at once. It would be very desirable to recreate something like Wikipedia's [What links here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:What_links_here) feature, to see what figures the section is talking about.

Some possible approaches:

- [`hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) has the `backref` and `pagebackref` options (pp. 10, 33–35 of the package [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf)), which seem to provide this exact functionality, but for bibliography items only. One could perhaps combine the relevant `\ref{}` commands with the `\cite{}` command, then create and display a single bibliography entry at each appendix section ([related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38580/displaying-selected-bibliographic-items-in-the-body-of-the-text)), and make everything but the `backref` list of said entry invisible. Sounds horrible.
- I suppose that one could also create dozens of different indices ([related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-two-or-more-distinct-indexes)), each with only one entry, but that seems rather inconvenient, and, I could imagine, might slow down compilation. Sounds horrible, too.
- Do some wizardy way beyond my grasp. Sounds... bewitching.

Ideally, the solution would work regardless of whether we're using figures/sections/listings/etc. in the main text or in the appendix, and allow for some amount of customization (e.g. choosing whether to list page numbers or figure numbers).

Minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{for more info, see \ref{appendix:some-entry}}\label{fig:1} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{for more info, see \ref{appendix:some-entry}}\label{fig:2} 
\end{figure}

\subsection{Some Appendix Entry}\label{appendix:some-entry}

What links here: Figures \ref{fig:1} and \ref{fig:2}. % How can I automate this?

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: Tried to read the [`backref.dtx`](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/blob/master/backref.dtx) file of the [`hyperref`](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref) bundle on GitHub to see if I could use (or slightly modify) its functionality, but I just got confused (tried to use `\backcite{}{{}{}{}}` in combination with `\backrefparscanfalse` and then `\backrefprint` manually, but to no avail (`\@xdblarg` error, and probably plenty more hidden from sight). If  someone from the LaTeX3 Project, or perhaps even the creator of the `backref` module, David Carlisle, could help out, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with `\listoffigures` ?

Comment: @Fran 1. It lists all figures, not just a selected few, 2. the formatting (the desired result is a list as in the MWE), 3. defining multiple `\listoffigures` (if that's even possible) to deal with 1 is probably just as tedious as the first two approaches considered above.